# Why does eval need to be used to input 3**631+29 to the int function?

Tags: python

```
res=0
num=int(input("Enter a positive integer:"))
while num>0:
     res=res+(num % 10)
     num=num//10
 print (res)
```

Why when the input is `3**631+29` is there a problem? And why can `eval` fix this?
As I see the program output will be to show "step by step" summing of the digits in the input integer, so is it because `3**631+29` isn't an integer but a string? But why is `eval` involved?

Comment: That's not an integer, it's an arithmetic *expression*.

Comment: (assuming you're on python 3) because `int` doesn't know what to do with the string literal `'3**631+29'`.  Just like it wouldn't know what to do with `'banana pancakes'` - even though *I* know what to do with banana pancakes, `int` doesn't.

Answer (score 8):

`int` takes as a parameter (a string representing) an integer **literal**, not an arbitrary arithmetic expression.

`eval` takes a string and evaluates it, i.e. it "runs" it as if it were code. As `3**631+26` is a valid python expression (the sum of 3 to the 631st power and 26), `eval` works in your case, but opens your application to code injection. (What happens if the user enters e.g. `__import__('sys').exit(0)`?)

Comment: @ Hyperboreus what does "code injection" mean? does it mean to seek for proper variable from the given input?

Comment: "code injection" means making your program run any arbitrary code - which is what `eval` do.  https://www.google.com/search?q=code+injection

Comment: but having `3**631+26` it will work on it and interpret it finally as an integer?

Comment: @user7777777 Yes it will. But if you know the input a priori, why ask the user to input it?

Answer (score 2):

The `int` function expects a string with a sequence of digits ('0' to '9') to convert it into an integer. If there are other symbols like `*` then it is not able to parse that string.

Comment: I know what you mean, but `+` may not be the best example :^) because `int("+23")` works..